# Los JButton no funcionan

Tags: java, icons

Estoy tratando de poner un ícono en el JButton con uno de los constructores de la clase JButton. Cuando ejecuto este proyecto, los tres botones no aparecen, pero cuando uso un constructor sin un ícono, se muestran los tres botones. No sé por qué no funciona, no sé si es algo que estoy haciendo mal o solo en mi computadora no funciona. Dejo el código a continuación.

```
package graficos;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PruebaAcciones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoAcciones mimarco = new MarcoAcciones();
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

class MarcoAcciones extends JFrame {

    public MarcoAcciones() {

        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(300,100,600,300);

        add(new PanelAccion());
    }
}

class PanelAccion extends JPanel {

    public PanelAccion() {

        AccionColor accionAmarillo = new AccionColor("Amarillo", new ImageIcon("src/graficos/iconoAmarillo"), Color.YELLOW);
        AccionColor accionAzul = new AccionColor("Azul", new ImageIcon("src/graficos/iconoAzul"), Color.BLUE);
        AccionColor accionRojo = new AccionColor("Rojo", new ImageIcon("src/graficos/iconoRojo"), Color.RED);

        add(new JButton(accionAmarillo));
        add(new JButton(accionAzul));
        add(new JButton(accionRojo));

        /*JButton  botonAmarillo = new JButton("Amarillo");
        JButton  botonAzul = new JButton("Azul");
        JButton  botonRojo = new JButton("Rojo");

        add(botonAmarillo);
        add(botonAzul);
        add(botonRojo);*/
    }

    /* Se pasó esta clase como interna de PanelAccion ya que se nesecita usar, dentro
     * de esta clase, el método setBackground() que pertenece a la clase JPanel, 
     * no a AbstractAction ni a la interfaz Action, así podemos usar ese método
     * (setBackground) aún sin heredar de JPanel */
    private class AccionColor extends AbstractAction { //Es la clase adaptadora de la interface Action

        public AccionColor(String nombre, Icon icono, Color colorBoton) {

            //Mandando información a traves del objeto de tipo Action
            putValue(Action.NAME, nombre);
            putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icono);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Poner la lámina de color " + colorBoton);
            putValue("colorDeFondo", colorBoton);
        }

        public AccionColor(String nombre, Color colorBoton) {

            //Mandando información a traves del objeto de tipo Action
            putValue(Action.NAME, nombre);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Poner la lámina de color " + colorBoton);
            putValue("colorDeFondo", colorBoton);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Color c = (Color) getValue("colorDeFondo"); //Se hace un casting ya que getValue devuelve string
            setBackground(c);

            System.out.println("Nombre: " + getValue(Action.NAME) + " Descripción: " + getValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION));
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa las rutas hacia los iconos y no se te olviden las extensiones, por ejemplo '.gif'  . Saluda a Juan Gómez ;)

Comment: Las rutas están bien, todo lo hice siguiendo el ejemplo de él y no me funciona

Comment: ¿Pero le has puesto las respectivas extensiones a esos iconos `new ImageIcon("datosEjemplos/azul.png")`, algo tal que así??

Comment: Si, ya lo probé así y no funciona

Comment: También tienes mal colocado el `setVisible(true) en la clase MarcoAcciones, colócalo al final del constructor de esa clase o al final del main. He probado tu ejemplo, y hay que redimensionar el marco para que se vean los botones.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que has reescrito, me sería de mucha ayuda

Comment: Voy a dejarte una respuesta. ;)

Comment: ¡¡Gracias!! Notable alumno de Juan Gómez :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código, tenemos 2 problemas..

**1)** En los enlaces que ponemos dentro de los argumentos de `ImageIcon`, debemos darle una extensión a nuestros iconos *'.gif, .png, etc'*.

```
new ImageIcon("src/amarillo.png")
```

**2)** Y el segundo a la hora de hacer visible nuestro marco. Siempre es conveniente llamar al método `setVisible()` en el último momento, o puede que tengamos problemas a la hora de que se nos muestren los componentes dentro del marco.
Una manera eficaz es llamarlo en el main de la aplicación en tu ejemplo..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoAcciones mimarco = new MarcoAcciones();
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mimarco.setVisible(true);
    }
```

---

Te dejo el ejercicio al completo y el resultado del mismo..

```
public class PruebaAcciones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoAcciones mimarco = new MarcoAcciones();
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mimarco.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class MarcoAcciones extends JFrame {

    public MarcoAcciones() {
        setBounds(300,100,600,300);
        add(new PanelAccion());
    }
}

class PanelAccion extends JPanel {

    public PanelAccion() {

        AccionColor accionAmarillo = new AccionColor("Amarillo", new ImageIcon("src/amarillo.png"), Color.YELLOW);
        AccionColor accionAzul = new AccionColor("Azul", new ImageIcon("src/azul.png"), Color.BLUE);
        AccionColor accionRojo = new AccionColor("Rojo", new ImageIcon("src/rojo.png"), Color.RED);

        add(new JButton(accionAmarillo));
        add(new JButton(accionAzul));
        add(new JButton(accionRojo));

    }

    /* Se pasó esta clase como interna de PanelAccion ya que se nesecita usar, dentro
     * de esta clase, el método setBackground() que pertenece a la clase JPanel, 
     * no a AbstractAction ni a la interfaz Action, así podemos usar ese método
     * (setBackground) aún sin heredar de JPanel */
    private class AccionColor extends AbstractAction { //Es la clase adaptadora de la interface Action

        public AccionColor(String nombre, Icon icono, Color colorBoton) {

            //Mandando información a traves del objeto de tipo Action
            putValue(Action.NAME, nombre);
            putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icono);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Poner la lámina de color " + colorBoton);
            putValue("colorDeFondo", colorBoton);
        }

        public AccionColor(String nombre, Color colorBoton) {

            //Mandando información a traves del objeto de tipo Action
            putValue(Action.NAME, nombre);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Poner la lámina de color " + colorBoton);
            putValue("colorDeFondo", colorBoton);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Color c = (Color) getValue("colorDeFondo"); //Se hace un casting ya que getValue devuelve string
            setBackground(c);

            System.out.println("Nombre: " + getValue(Action.NAME) + " Descripción: " + getValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION));
        } 

    }
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los iconos en mi ejemplo, los tengo dentro del paquete por defecto, dentro de la carpeta src. Saludos!

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!! :D

Comment: Un placer poder ayudar. Saludos!